# discord.py creating text channel in a specific category

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want to create a text channel in a certain category, but I got this error:
**AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'**
and here is the code:

```
overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)  
    }
    category = ctx.guild.categories[2].id
    await guild.create_text_channel(name='test', category=category, overwrites=overwrites)
```

I looked API References but i couldn't find anything. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `CategoryChannel` object directly to `create_text_channel`, not it's id.  You can use the `CategoryChannel.create_text_channel` method as a shortcut:

```
overwrites = {
    guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
    guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)  
}
await ctx.guild.categories[2].create_text_channel(name='test', category=category, overwrites=overwrites)
```